# Simple custom syntax in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I would like that for files with `.vm` extension vim would:

- colour in red all the words between two back-ticks like `` `this` ``,
- colour in yellow what is between two dollars like `$this is in yellow$`,
- and colour in green all words between `#` and the end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Syntax script

Create a file `~/.vim/syntax/vm.vim` with the following contents:

```
" Quit when a syntax file was already loaded.
if exists('b:current_syntax') | finish|  endif

syntax match vmBackticks "`\zs[^`]\+\ze`"
syntax match vmDollars "\$\zs[^$]\+\ze\$"
syntax match vmComment "#.*$"

hi def link vmBackticks Identifier
hi def link vmDollars Statement
hi def link vmComment Comment

let b:current_syntax = 'vm'
```

If you want to include the backticks / dollars in the highlighting, just drop the `\zs` and `\ze`.

That matches the three syntax elements, and provides default colors. One doesn't generally define explicit colors, but instead links to default *highlighting groups* defined by your colorscheme. You can list all via `:hi`. For tweaking, read `:help :syntax` and `:help usr_44.txt`, and have a look at the syntax scripts that ship with Vim.

#### Filetype detection

So far, you have to manually `:set syntax=vm` to active. To do this automatically, you have to teach Vim about your new *filetype*.

Create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/vm.vim` with the following contents:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.vm setf vm
```

This assumes that the files can be identified via the file name (cp. `:help autocmd-patterns`). You can also detect based on the path (file location), or even the contents. `:help new-filetype` has details.